# Getting this message in terminal. It's repeatedly posting with small time intervals

Tags: command-line, wine, winetricks

```
004d:fixme:bcrypt:BCryptCreateHash ignoring object buffer
0054:fixme:ntdll:server_ioctl_file Unsupported ioctl 4004747b (device=4004 access=1 func=d1e method=3)
0054:fixme:winsock:server_ioctl_sock Unsupported ioctl 4004747b (device=4004 access=1 func=d1e method=3)
0054:fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl unsupported WS_IOCTL cmd (_IOR('t', 123, 4))
```

What does this mean and how to get rid of it? Today I installed wine& winetricks and Minecraft Dungeons and then completely removed both. No other changes has be done before this message started popping

Comment: nothing. When I have terminal open and it stays idle for several seconds these lines keep repeating

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat ~/.bashrc` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

And then check if the terminal starts something that can't be found by the system and remove it.